# Not authorized to perform this action when admin login

Tags: yii

in file Controller:

```
class Controller extends CController
{
   public function filters()
    {
        return array('accessControl');
    }

    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',
                'actions' => array('login', 'logout'),
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow',
                'actions' => array('*'),
                'roles' => array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

in file WebUser:

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser
{
    public function checkAccess($operation, $params = array())
    {
        if (empty($this->id)) {
            return false;
        }

        $role = $this->getState("roles");

        if ($role === 'admin') {
            return true;
        }

        return ($operation === $role);
    }
}
```

in file UserIdentity:

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    private $id;

    public function authenticate()
    {
        $record = AdminModel::model()->findByAttributes(array(
                                              'username'=>$this->username));

        if ($record == null) {
            $this->errorCode = 'Username invalid';
        } elseif($record->password !== $this->password) {
            $this->errorCode = 'Password invalid';
        } elseif($record->level == 'banned') {
            $this->errorCode = 'Account being banned or not enabled';
        } else {
            $this->id = $record->id;
            $this->setState('nameDisplay', $record->display_name);
            $this->setState('roles', $record->level);
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
        }

        return !$this->errorCode;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

when login, i check: Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('admin'); //return true

but this is error: You are not authorized to perform this action. somebody can help me?

Comment: What does checkAccess return?

Answer (score -1):

I think this part of code is the problem:

```
 array('deny',
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),
```

It sais "Deny access to all pages for all users".
try to remove this part of code

Comment: so if you know the solution, why don't you write an answer